# On touch of third tab,the user should be able to make phone call. But user is redirected to make call on touch of second tab which is a wrong tab

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs

An activity has the three tabs on tab bar. First and second tab are used to display web page whereas the third tab is used to make phone call from application.

**Situation:** When user touch second tab from first, the user is redirected to phone call application which is not supposed to be it, and then it display the correct supposed to be web page. On the touch of third tab, it displays blank fragment rather than going for phone call. But, when the user go from third to second tab, it displays correct web page and do not divert to phone application. Also when I go from first to third tab, then it redirects user to make a phone call. Note that the third tab is only use to make phone call.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstancestate) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    web_personal = (WebView) layout.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = web_personal.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.getString("activity") == "Personal") {
            if (bundle.getInt("position") == 0) {
                web_personal.loadUrl("http://www.xxxxxxx.in/inddddddn/view/26/Hexxx%20xxxxx/");
            } else if (bundle.getInt("position") == 1) {
                web_personal.loadUrl("http://www.xxxxxxxx.in/xxxxxx/view/34/Senior%20Citizen%2xxxxxx/");
            } else if (bundle.getInt("position") == 2) {
                web_personal.loadUrl("http://www.xxxxxxx.in/xxxxx/view/25/Personal%20xxxxx%2dddddd%20xxx/");
            }
        } else if (bundle.getString("activity") == "Home")
        {
            if (bundle.getInt("position") == 0) {
                web_personal.loadUrl("http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.in/");
            }
           else if (bundle.getInt("position") == 1) {
              web_personal.loadUrl("http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.in/contactus/");
            }
            else if(bundle.getInt("position") == 2)
            {
               Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
               callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0980000000"));
               startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        }
    }
        return layout;
    }
```

[Layout of tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hCg0.png)

If I put webview's loadUrl function to display web page instead of call function then it display web page accordingly to the condition met in the If clause. Thereby we can negate the logic problem of if clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue is there because of caching the view.
If you debug the app yu will see that your onCreateView and onResume will be called when you reach the 2nd tab
so there is way:
First remove the code from onCreateView

```
yourViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        ...
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(position==2)
             //call your method in 3rd fragment
        }
    });
```

Comment: Assist me with the understanding of concept. If I put the code inside the onCreate View, how does callIntent gets called if I touch upon on second tab for first time after the app is run for first time. How can caching of view principle is applied for app run for first time ?

Comment: you put your code in on createView of your fragment. The standard view pager caches the fragment by default. to increase the performance of the tabs switching. so your view is created and cached before you actually swipe it.To make action when tab/fragment is visible you have to handle the pageChangeListener